# Is it possible to get the stored data from react-native-async-storage in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have an app in AppStore that is made in React-Native. I have now chosen to rewrite the entire app in Swift instead of React-native.

My question is whether it is possible to access the data stored on the device and retrieve it in Swift. I have stored the user's login token in react-native-async-storage and I need that token in Swift so that the user remains logged in when they update to the new version of the app.

My code in React-Native:

```
if (responseJson.status && responseJson.token && responseJson.login) {

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@logged_in', 'true');
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token', responseJson.token);
}
```

I really hope it can be done. The app sends a confirmation sms at login and since the app has really many users, this will quickly cost a lot of money.

Comment: You may want to look at this https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/brownfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
func getTokenFromReactNative() -> String? {

    let RCTStorageDirectory = "RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1"
    let RCTManifestFileName = "manifest.json"

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let appSupportDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

    let mySupportDirectory = appSupportDirectory!.appendingPathComponent(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)

    let storageDirectory = mySupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent(RCTStorageDirectory)

    let storageFile = storageDirectory.appendingPathComponent(RCTManifestFileName)

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: storageFile.path) {

        do {

            let stringFromFile = try String(contentsOf: storageFile, encoding: .utf8)

            let data = stringFromFile.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

            let dict = json as? [String: String]

            return dict?["@token"] ?? nil

        }
        catch {

            return nil

        }

    }
    
    return nil
    
}
```